# How to achieve anchor links on top of pages.

Tags: pages, links

I have been looking around for a plugin or a how-to but I been unable to find the answer.

I am trying to get a box with anchor links at the top of my pages. I can see and example on the official wordpress site.

See the right hand side that says 'Contents' and 'Related'.
 http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/page-jumps/

Does anyone know the best way to achieve something like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to do this **just** for anchor links within your current WP page, a table of contents style plugin will likely suffice; for example, see:  http://wordpress.org/plugins/table-of-contents-plus/

This specific example auto-generates the table of contents and anchors based on the headers in your document/page, so it is fairly low fuss on you as the end user.